# Responsive issue with background image in css

Tags: html, css, image

I have created a div with a class called "responsive_image" and inside that div i have a img tag. The code is,

```
<div class="responsive_image">
<img src="img1.png"/>
</div>
```

The css code is,

```
.responsive_image {
position: relative;
background: url(images/laptop.png) no-repeat center #f0f0f0;
width: 100%;
height: 190px;
text-align: center;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
}

.responsive_image img {
width: 240px;
height: 160px;
position: absolute;
top: 6%;
left: 16%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}
```

Actually, the `laptop.png` image is the original laptop image with size of 310x186 and inside that, a image with the size of 240x160 and that should correctly fixed inside the laptop image.

From the above code, everything seems to be work perfectly but while going for responsive, each and every time i need to adjust the top and left section in the `.responsive_image img`. Is there any solution so that i no need to alter top and left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `width:100%` from the `.responsive_image` class. And give `width:310px` as per your laptop image size

Also you have used `percentage` with `top and left` position. Change  it with `pixel`. As percentage have always dynamic behavior as per the screen size.  USE percentage only when you built a main structure of the html.

```
.responsive_image {
position: relative;
background: url(images/laptop.png) no-repeat center #f0f0f0;
width: 310px;
height: 190px;
text-align: center;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
}

.responsive_image img {
width: 240px;
height: 160px;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: working great. love you bro.. i marked this as answer